# How to dynamically construct a control name in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, loops

I am iterating through an array:

```
Dim dbConfig As New pbu_housingEntities
    Dim possible() As String = {"FROD", "FRCD", "SOOD", "SOCD", "JROD", "JRCD", "SROD", "SRCD", "SR5OD", "SR5CD"}
    For Each value As String In possible
        Dim current_value = value
        Dim exists = From p In dbConfig.Configs _
                     Where p.Description = current_value
                     Select p

        If exists.Count.Equals(0) Then
            Dim create As New Config
            create.Description = current_value
            dbConfig.Configs.AddObject(create)
            dbConfig.SaveChanges()
        Else
            Dim update_query = (From p In dbConfig.Configs _
                                Where p.Description = current_value _
                                Select p)
            update_query.First.Description = current_value
            update_query.First.dateValue = 
        End If
    Next
```

Towards the end of the array you can see update_query.First.dateValue =, I'd like to do something like this:

```
update_query.First.dateValue = "txt" + current_value + ".Text"
```

But I don't want it to return the literal txtcurrent_value.Text, but rather to return the text value of txtcurrent_value.Text. This is easy to do, if you know each control name - but in this case I'm iterating, otherwise I could do:

```
update_query.First.dateValue = txtNameofControl.Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a reference to the control like this:

```
TextBox tb = Page.FindControl("txt" + current_value) as TextBox;
update_query.First.dateValue = tb.Text;
```

Comment: I'm using this code but am running into an issue...the tb value always turns up as "Nothing" - even though I know a control exists with "txt" + current_value as its name!

Comment: If you're using a MasterPage, the path to find the control is a little different.  I don't know it off the top of my head, but I would say just keep trying to get to it.  try MasterPage.Page.Controls.FindControl or a variant of.